# Sqlite Database is Locked In Command line(adb shell)+Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I builded Sqlite database in android application.
First i builded main_category table in Sqlite Manager.And then i export that file to my application's raw folder.
My Export file is .sql file.
That it is here.

```
 CREATE TABLE "main_category" ("_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL ,"main_image" TEXT,"word_audio_file" TEXT,"char_audio_file" TEXT,"hash_record" BOOL NOT NULL ,"record" TEXT, "menu" TEXT);
    INSERT INTO "main_category" VALUES(1,'g_a.png','g_a.mp3','g_a_01.mp3','false',NULL,NULL);
```

So I read from my application using **FileInputStream.**
Code is here,

```
InputStream in= new InputStream() {

                @Override
                public int read() throws IOException {
                    File sqlfile1 = new File("C://CellCity//workspace//GokiriKidApp//res//raw//main_category.sql");
                    return 0;
                }
            };
            try {

                InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(in);
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);

                SQL_MAIN_CATEGORY= br.readLine();
                in.close();
                br.close();
                isr.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.i("onCreate", "Database Creation");
            String categoryTString=SQL_MAIN_CATEGORY;
            db.execSQL(categoryTString);
```

So When i run my code i got error: **OutOfMemoryError** and lock database in command line(adb shell)

Comment: Are you running this code in an Android application?

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing a file on your computer, not on the Android device here:

```
 File sqlfile1 = new File("C://CellCity//workspace//GokiriKidApp//res//raw//main_category.sql");
```

If you have placed the file you want to read in the raw folder, then you reference its location on the device using [`openRawResource(R.raw.fileName)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource%28int%29)

This will return an inputStream that you can use to read the file, instead of having to create a File object and an inputStream yourself.